# Mac OS X Yosemite: autofsd/automountd slows down command line programs

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, automount

I noticed that some common commands(ls, cat, touch, etc.) run very slow on my Mac. I couldn't find out why. So I use `top` to monitor cpu usage after I run some program in a terminal. I found that no matter what program I am running, a process called `automountd` pops up immediately and starts using lots of cpu (60% - 70%). I feel this might be the cause. If so, why this happened? What should I do?

Edit: I've confirmed that `automontd/autofsd` slows down my command line. After I kill the `autofsd`, `ls` and other commands become responsive. But disabling `autofsd` doesn't seem to be a perfect solution, so I hope someone can shed some light on this.